# handling events on custom components

Tags: reactjs

I have these files:

**button.module.css**

```
.base {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.normal {
    composes: base;
    color:black;
    background-color: #aeeeb7;
    border: 1px solid #42924d;;
}

.danger {
    composes: base;
    color:black;
    background-color: rgb(253, 128, 128);
    border: 1px solid rgb(196, 108, 108);
}
```

**button.js**

```
import classes from './button.module.css';

const ButtonTypes = {
    'normal': classes.normal, 
    'danger': classes.danger
};

const Button = (props) => {
    const className = ButtonTypes[props.type] ? ButtonTypes[props.type] : classes.normal;
    return <div role="button" className={className} ...props>{text}</div>;
}

export default Button;
```

**app.js**

```
import Button from './button';

const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('app');
  }

  const handleMouseOver = () => {
    console.log('mouse-over');
  }

  ...

  return (
     <div>
       <Button type="normal" onClick=(handleClick) onMouseOver={handleMouseOver} ...>
     </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

I am changing the class of the button depending on the "type" property. (It could be other components not just a button)

How should I handle events on the custom component? Is the way I am passing them right now to that div inside fine or I should do it differently?

I want to create some custom components and I am trying to verify I am doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion here. Instead of spreading all props in button. You can destructure out the required props and then spread the rest props.

```js
import classes from "./button.module.css";

const ButtonTypes = {
  normal: classes.normal,
  danger: classes.danger
};

const Button = ({ type, ...rest }) => {
  const className = ButtonTypes[type] ? ButtonTypes[type] : classes.normal;
  return (
    <div role="button" className={className} {...rest}>
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```